# Log file management with python

Tags: python-3.x, syslog

I got a file that has lots of different events from some service, I want to break those events in to different lines, and remove some "words & elements"
Example of log file:

```
"Event1":{"Time":"2022-12-16 16:04:16","Username":"IAmUser1@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action1","Data":"Datahere"},"Event2":{"Time":"2022-12-16 16:03:59","Username":"IAmUser2@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action2","Data":"Datahere"},"Event3":{"Time":"2022-12-16 15:54:56","Username":"IAmUser3@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action3","Data":"Datahere"},
```

As you see they all start with "EventX", At the end I want to see:

```
{"Time":"2022-12-16 16:04:16","Username":"IAmUser1@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action1","Data":"Datahere"}
{"Time":"2022-12-16 16:03:59","Username":"IAmUser2@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action2","Data":"Datahere"}
{"Time":"2022-12-16 15:54:56","Username":"IAmUser3@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action3","Data":"Datahere"},
```

As you see "EventX": and "," are removed and each event is now a new line at the file.

Just a beginner here with Python and cannot figure this one out.

Thanks

tried combining re.search & re.findall without luck,
Also tried to find a way to copy only things between {} and add those later and again no luck here.

Comment: is your desired output "just the text" as you show or are you hoping to make a list of dictionaries that have the data elements shown...  a data structure output?

Comment: Hey, just as text. All the rest is done by the service that receives this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct below works and makes a list of dictionaries from your data.  You could smash down some of this syntax with list or dictionary comprehensions, but it isn't needed.

If you are having trouble with testing the `regex` expressions, this [site](https://regex101.com) is invaluable.

##### Code

```
import regex as re

data = '''"Event1":{"Time":"2022-12-16 16:04:16","Username":"IAmUser1@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action1","Data":"Datahere"},"Event2":{"Time":"2022-12-16 16:03:59","Username":"IAmUser2@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action2","Data":"Datahere"},"Event3":{"Time":"2022-12-16 15:54:56","Username":"IAmUser3@gmail.com","IP_Address":"1.1.1.1","Action":"Action3","Data":"Datahere"},'''

splitter = r'"Event\d+":{(.*?)}'  # a search pattern to capture the stuff in braces

# tokenize the data source...
tokens = re.findall(splitter, data)

#print(tokens)


# now we can operate on the tokens and split them up into key-value pairs and put them into a list
result = []
for token in tokens:
    # make an empty dictionary to hold the row elements
    line_dict = {}
    # we can split the line (token) by comma to get the key-value pairs
    pairs = token.split(',')
    for pair in pairs:
        # another regex split needed here, because the timestamps have colons too
        splitter = r'"(.*)"\s*:\s*"(.*)"'    # capture two groups of things in quotes on opposite sides of colon
        parts = re.search(splitter, pair)
        key, value = parts.group(1), parts.group(2)
        line_dict[key] = value
    # add the dictionary of line elements to the result
    result.append(line_dict)

for d in result:
    print(d)
```

##### Output:

```
{'Time': '2022-12-16 16:04:16', 'Username': 'IAmUser1@gmail.com', 'IP_Address': '1.1.1.1', 'Action': 'Action1', 'Data': 'Datahere'}
{'Time': '2022-12-16 16:03:59', 'Username': 'IAmUser2@gmail.com', 'IP_Address': '1.1.1.1', 'Action': 'Action2', 'Data': 'Datahere'}
{'Time': '2022-12-16 15:54:56', 'Username': 'IAmUser3@gmail.com', 'IP_Address': '1.1.1.1', 'Action': 'Action3', 'Data': 'Datahere'}
```

=========

Edit:

If you are having trouble getting the data out of the file, try something like this (and experiment...it isn't clear exactly how your file is formatted/linebreaks, etc.

```
f_name = 'logfile.txt'

# use a context manager (look it up)
with open(f_name, 'r') as src:
    data = src.readlines()

# check it!
print(data)
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go, but when changed the data to be a file "open("myfile.txt", "w")" getting the error: 

Exception has occurred: TypeError
expected string or bytes-like object, got '_io.TextIOWrapper'
  File "/log/testlines", line 16, in <module>
    tokens = re.findall(splitter, data)

Comment: You should be opening the file in read mode, not write mode.  Use 'r'.  And you will need to read the data....  See my edit.

Comment: Getting another error now, expected string or bytes-like object, got 'list'.
Regarding the list its just a long text file with the included log inside nothing else.
Again thanks for helping.