# Save json list in a text file

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

I got a json log file that i rearrange to be correct, after this i am trying to save the results to the same file. The results are a list. but the problem that i am unable to save and will give me the following error:

```
write() argument must be str, not list
```

Here is the code it self:

```
import regex as re
import re


f_name = 'test1.txt'

splitter = r'"Event\d+":{(.*?)}'  # a search pattern to capture the stuff in braces

#Open the file as Read.
with open(f_name, 'r') as src:
    data = src.readlines()

# tokenize the data source...
tokens = re.findall(splitter, str(data))

#print(tokens)


# now we can operate on the tokens and split them up into key-value pairs and put them into a list
result = []
for token in tokens:
    # make an empty dictionary to hold the row elements
    line_dict = {}
    # we can split the line (token) by comma to get the key-value pairs
    pairs = token.split(',')
    for pair in pairs:
        # another regex split needed here, because the timestamps have colons too
        splitter = r'"(.*)"\s*:\s*"(.*)"'    # capture two groups of things in quotes on opposite sides of colon
        parts = re.search(splitter, pair)
        key, value = parts.group(1), parts.group(2)
        line_dict[key] = value
    # add the dictionary of line elements to the result
    result.append(line_dict)


with open(f_name, 'w') as src:
   for line in result:
     src.write(result)
```

i.e the code it self was not written by me -> [Log file management with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74830163/log-file-management-with-python) (thanks AirSquid)
Thanks for the assistance, New at Python here.

Tried to import json and use json.dump, also tried to append the text, but in most cases i end up with just [] or empty file.

Comment: Did you mean `src.write(line)` ?

Comment: Yeah, went ahead and fixed this, was getting dict error and tried to use json.dump but now its all 1 endless line and not as the screenshot, any idea to save them and still keep 1 json log line per line?

Comment: You can try `src.write(json.dumps(line) + '\n')`